# from localhost auto moves to online server

Tags: magento-2.1

Hi I made a copy of all the files and database of my online site.

I uploaded everything to XAMPP on localhost  because I wanted to test a few extension.

when I go to localhost/magento everything works properly. but when I click any link, it takes me to my online site, not localhost. I changed the page in the database (attachment). What could be wrong ?

[image]

Comment: remove your `cache:storage` and execute `reindex` command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should follow below step to in order to setup  a system at live:**

First at Changes the Local url to live at database.Run below mysql query for get list of url:

```
SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` where path IN ('web/unsecure/base_url','web/secure/base_url','web/unsecure/base_link_url','web/secure/base_link_url')
```

Then on `app/etc/env.php` file changes db ***credential*** and put the live one.

Now,delete *all cache file which is created*.Just goto **magento dir/var 
delete all file**s from folder cache ***page_cache view_preprocessed***

***Also truncate database table cache,cache_tag.***